# Split button on hover

Tags: php, javascript, html

I'm looking for a solution to split on hover one graphic based button into two. Both buttons will have a link to a website. 
I need to do this with HTML, JS or PHP.

How is it possible to manage?

**Update for Clarification**

1. There is a big button graphic on my index page that says "Enter".
2. By going over the button the "enter" button goes away
3. Two new buttons show up on that exact position.
4. The first says "English version" and the other "Spanish version"
5. When the mouse leave the area, the original button shows back up and the two language buttons disappear

Comment: Do you want the buttons to merge back together when the mouse leaves the area where the button used to be?

Comment: Yes. What I want to archive is this: There is a big button graphic on my index page that says "Enter". By going over the button the "enter" button goes away and two new buttons show up on that exactly position. The first says "English version" and the other "Spanish version".

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using javascript with jquery and jqueryui.Button

Example from the jqueryui website:

> http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/#splitbutton

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#rerun" )
            .button()
            .click(function() {
                alert( "Running the last action" );
            })
            .next()
                .button( {
                    text: false,
                    icons: {
                        primary: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s"
                    }
                })
                .click(function() {
                    alert( "Could display a menu to select an action" );
                })
                .parent()
                    .buttonset();
    });
</script>

<div class="demo">

<div>
    <button id="rerun">Run last action</button>
    <button id="select">Select an action</button>
</div>

</div><!-- End demo -->
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't have to be complicated. Instead of messing around with a bunch of button manipulation, just use a div background-image for your "enter" button in the front layer, then put two linked images under it. When you hover over the div, the front layer hides, revealing the two buttons underneath. More details:

1. Create a `<div id="wrapper">` element with an explicitly defined height and width and `position:relative`. This will be the div that contains your big submit button as well as your two "split" buttons.
2. Create a `<div id="enter">` inside the wrapper with the same width and height. Set the css `background-image` to be whatever you want it to show. Also, set these css properties: `position:absolute; top:0, left:0; z-index:5;`
3. Create two `img` elements inside the wrapper as well. Both of these should have no margin/padding/border, the same height as the wrapper div, and half the width. Then link both of them to whatever page you want.

So the html will look something like this:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="enter"></div> <!-- in front of the imgs. fades out when mouseover #wrapper -->
    <a href="#"><img src="#" /></a> <!-- which reveals these two images -->
    <A href="#"><img src="#" /></a>
</div>
```

I suggest you use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) instead of vanilla javascript (it'll make your life a lot easier). This will hide the "enter" div whenever you hover over it, revealing the two img elements that you can then click on:

```
$('#wrapper').hover(function(){
    $('#enter').fadeOut();
}, function(){
    $('#enter').fadeIn();
}
```

Hope that helps.